Issue with Tooltip Effect Not Appearing Over Button - Need Assistance
I'm facing an issue while trying to create a tooltip for the "Back-end" button on my web page. The tooltip effect isn't appearing over the button, and I'm having trouble figuring out why.
Here's the code I'm using:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/interface1.css">
    <title>interface</title>

<style>
/* Styles for the "Back-end" button */
.back-end_link{
    display: flex;
}
.back-end_link button{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.993);
    color: aliceblue;
    border: transparent;
    transition: 0.5s;
    font-size: 30px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.back-end_link button:hover{
    border: none;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.949);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.485);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.373);
    transform: scale(0.9);
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgb(255, 255, 255), 0 0 40px rgb(255, 255, 255), 0 0 80px rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.details-back-end{
    color: #fff;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
.back-end_link:hover .details-back-end{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.details{
    font-family: "Kanit", sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 1100px;
    color: aliceblue;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.575);
}
</style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
       
        <div class="login-registro">
            <div class="login">
                <button id="login-button">
                    <a href="login.html">
                        login
                    </a>
                </button>
            </div>
        <div class="register">
             <button class="register-button">
                <a href="registro.html">
                    registre-se  
                </a>
             </button>
        </div>
    </div><!--div login-registro-->
        <div class="front-back">
            <div class="front-end_link">
                <a href="#">
                    <button>
                FRONT-END
            </button>
                </a>
        </div>
            <div class="back-end_link">
                <a href="#">
                    <button>
                BACK-END
            </button>
                </a>    
       
        </div>
            </div><!--div front-back-->
        <div class="details">
          <p class="details-front-end">
           DETAILS ABOUT FRONT-END
          </p>
          <p class="details-back-end">
            DETAILS ABOUT BACK-END
          </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</body>
</html>

I've tried several things to fix the issue, but the tooltip simply doesn't appear when hovering over the "Back-end" button.
If anyone can help me identify what I'm doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it!
Thank you.

The problem is that you are trying to select the class details-back-end as if it's a child of back-end_link... Which it isn't... The simplest solution would be to use JavaScript. There may be a way to do this with css, but I'm unsure of it, and if there is, its likely to be very messy.

As far as I can see from your code, you want to have a tooltip when you hover an html object, a button in this case. This page shows a very simple way to create tooltips on hover.
The code would look something like this:


.tooltip {
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/interface1.css">
  <title>interface</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="tooltip">Hover over me
    <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




however I need to use this on the button, as you can see, since I put an effect on top of the button link of the backend button


however I need to use this on the button, as you can see, since I put an effect on top of the button link of the backend button



@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100..900&family=Nunito+Sans:ital,opsz,wght@0,6..12,200..1000;1,6..12,200..1000&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Tilt+Neon&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100..900&family=Kanit:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Nunito+Sans:ital,opsz,wght@0,6..12,200..1000;1,6..12,200..1000&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Tilt+Neon&display=swap');
@font-face {
    font-family: "Nunito Sans", sans-serif;
    src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100..900&family=Nunito+Sans:ital,opsz,wght@0,6..12,200..1000;1,6..12,200..1000&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Tilt+Neon&display=swap');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Kanit", sans-serif;
    src: url ('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100..900&family=Kanit:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Nunito+Sans:ital,opsz,wght@0,6..12,200..1000;1,6..12,200..1000&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Tilt+Neon&display=swap');
}
body{
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    background: url(../imgs/pexels-david-besh-884788.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-size: 100%;
}
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
    background: transparent;
}
.login-registro{
    margin-bottom: 20%;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
}
.login-registro a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
.login-registro button{
    border: transparent;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.274);
}
.login-registro button:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
}
.login{
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.register{
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 20px;
}


.front-back{
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: "Nunito Sans", sans-serif;
}
.front-back button{
    height: 200px;
    width: 350px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.625);
}
.front-back a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.front-end_link{
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 400px;
}
.front-end_link button{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
    border: none;
    transition: 0.5s;
    font-size: 30px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048);
}
.front-end_link button:hover{
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.373);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgb(0, 0, 0), 0 0 40px rgb(0, 0, 0), 0 0 80px rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.back-end_link{
    display: flex;
}
.back-end_link button{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.993);
    color: aliceblue;
    border: transparent;
    transition: 0.5s;
    font-size: 30px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.back-end_link button:hover{
    border: none;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.949);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.485);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.373);
    transform: scale(0.9);
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgb(255, 255, 255), 0 0 40px rgb(255, 255, 255), 0 0 80px rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.details-back-end{
    color: #fff;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.back-end_link button .details-back-end::after{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}

.back-end_link button .details-back-end{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.back-end_link button:hover .details-back-end{
    visibility: visible;
}
.details{
    font-family: "Kanit", sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 1100px;
    color: aliceblue;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.575);
}
.details-front-end{
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 530px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../TCC - BREAKMAN/style/interface1.css">
    <title>interface</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
       
        <div class="login-registro">
            <div class="login">
                <button id="login-button">
                    <a href="login.html">
                        login
                    </a>
                </button>
            </div>
        <div class="register">
             <button class="register-button">
                <a href="registro.html">
                    registre-se  
                </a>
             </button>
        </div>
    </div><!--div login-registro-->
        <div class="front-back">
            <div class="front-end_link">
                <a href="#">
                    <button>
                FRONT-END
            </button>
                </a>
        </div>
            <div class="back-end_link">
                <a href="#">
                    <button>
                BACK-END
            </button>
                </a>    
       
        </div>
            </div><!--div front-back-->
        <div class="details">
          <p class="details-front-end">
           DETALHES SOBRE O FRONT-END
          </p>
          <p class="details-back-end">
            DETALHES SOBRE O BACK-END
          </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</body>
</html>



